# The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I Just uploaded my app in App Store when am trying to check the build status in itunes connect, it says processing for over 3 hours, while i was uploading the App i got the following warning,

The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message.

Anybody faced similar issue

Comment: I have this issues since Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 applications. Besides, in my case all those build with this warning are stuck in the "Processing" mode. Frustrating.

Comment: Did you figure out how to make it work? It's happening to me right now. (It's indeed frustrating).

Comment: Happened to me too. i'm using Objective-C and Swift 2 with Xcode 7. App is in "Processing mode" for now.

Comment: One of the reason might be invalid image size or resolutions,despite this error i went ahead and submitted the app, apple immediately sent a mail to my developer account saying so and so images are of invalid resolution or has alpha channel,go ahead and with submission and check your email.hope this helps :)

Comment: My build upload to the App Store had the same warning. Was in "processing mode" but has passed this state and is now in "Waiting for Review" so I suppose it's ok.